How to combine multiple models into one by combining pre-trained layers using Keras
I have multiple models pretrained to classification. I want to combine them into one model. Each of those models contain the same EfficentNet and Resnet achitecture, then there is concatenate layer and Conv then Dense layers. I want to remove Resnet and  EfficentNet from each model and use only one for whole 'final_model'. Previously models were trained on frozen EfficentNet and Resnet using imagenet weights.
I've tried solution like this but when i try to validate if weights are the same by running this model on test dataset it gives me random output.
shared_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name="shared_input")

efficient_net = EfficientNetB7(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3))
resnet = ResNet152(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3))

efficient_net = efficient_net(shared_input)
resnet = resnet(shared_input)

shared_conc = Concatenate()([efficient_net, resnet])

for i in range(ammount_of_models):
    model = load_model(f"model_nb_{i}.keras")
    small_model= Model(model.layers[4].input, model.layers[-1].output)
    small_model.append(small_model(shared_conc))

combined_output = Concatenate(name="final_output")(lighweight_outputs)
final_model = Model(inputs=[shared_input], outputs=[combined_output])


concatenating the outputs does not make any sense, maybe you want to take the average of the outputs instead? if not you should specify exactly what "combining models" means for you.
